# Overloading method on child controller method on mapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, overloading

i tried to create RestApi service with Spring boot

I have parent class

> ```
> public abstract class GenericRestController{
>
>    @RequestMapping(
>             produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
>             method = RequestMethod.GET,
>             path = "/list"
>     )
>     @ApiOperation("Get all entities")
>     public SimpleResponse create(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer size) {
> ..somehting
> }
>
> }
> ```

and

> ```
>  @RestController 
>  @Api("Parameters") 
>  @RequestMapping(value = Controller.PARAMETERS) 
>  public class ParameterController extends
>  GenericRestController {
>
>      @RequestMapping(
>              produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
>              method = RequestMethod.POST,
>              consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
>
>      )
>      @ApiOperation("Create new entity")
>      public SimpleResponse create(@RequestBody Parameter parameter,
>                                   @PathVariable(value = "rate-id") Long rateId) { ...something
>      }
>
>  }
> ```

I get error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'parameterController' method 
public kz.sanscrit.cbs.common.pojo.SimpleResponse kz.sanscrit.cbs.rates.controllers.GenericRestController.create(E)
to {[/rates/{rate-id}/parameters],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}: There is already 'parameterController' bean method
```

How I can properly overload this method, because I need to extend other methods from this GenericClass, but in case of create I had other additional parameter

Answer (score 0):

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711472/5899903).

> One @Controller-annotated class should not extend another @Controller-annotated class, because the parent class's methods also exist on the child class.

As noted in the answer, you can't extend the controller as you are trying to achieve.